# Intellij trying to treat pom.xml as jar file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

While trying to run test (on a maven project) from Intellij , I am constantly getting below mentioned error

```
[my-module] Exception in parsing jar file for extract from jar: /path/to/pom.xml java.util.zip.ZipException: The JAR/ZIP file (/path/to/pom.xml) seems corrupted, error: error in opening zip file
```

However all maven cycles run well when run from the command line.

Has anyone faced this issue before ?

I have already tried all these things

1. Invalidated Intellij Idea
2. Deleted my .m2 repo and recreated the project

Comment: Did you change it in `Settings` | `File Types`?

Comment: Intellij Idea version is 11.1.4

Comment: Check that `pom.xml` or `*.xml` is **NOT** added [here](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/573/20121227105240.png).

Comment: nopes ,neither is added as an archive file.

Comment: Can you share a project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: ok , finally fixed.The osgi facets apparently were responsible.The issue was resolved once the facet was removed.Do not know the exact reason,but with both maven and osgi facet present,they might have been stepping on each others shoes.

Answer (score 8):

ok , finally fixed.The osgi facets apparently were responsible.The issue was resolved once the facet was removed.Do not know the exact reason but the intellij osgi facet is known to be unstable. More info [here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/03/4-reasons-not-using-osmorc-anymore/)

Comment: I've encounted this issue with IntelliJ 15.0.1. I removed the OSGi facets from the modules that were failing and it compiled successfully. For anyone else experiencing this issue, you can remove this through Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Facets; select the module that's broken and remove the facet.

Answer (score 0):

Even in 2020 this IntelliJ (Ultimate 2019.2) plugin tries to open a pom.xml file as a jar file. Disabling the OSGI plugin helped in my case:

[image]

[image]