# Error while running tests on IntelliJ for OSGi bundle

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2018.1.1 for Linux

While trying to run test on a maven project consisting of OSGi bundles from Intellij , I am constantly getting below mentioned errors

```
Error:osgi: [org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth] In component <name not yet determined>, method framework.authentication.context.method.name.translator,  cannot recognize the signature of the descriptor: ()V
Error:osgi: [org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth] In component class org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.internal.OAuth2ServiceComponent, reference framework.authentication.context.method.name.translator is dynamic but has no unbind method.
Error:osgi: [org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth] No interface specified on framework.authentication.context.method.name.translator
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: It looks a bit like the bundle you compiled against is not the same (or compatible) to the bundle your test runs with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050351/intellij-trying-to-treat-pom-xml-as-jar-file?rq=1).

This issue got resolved by removing the OSGi facets in the project and the tests were successful.

To remove OSGi facets, go to Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Facets; select and remove OSGi facets.

Answer (score 0):

the issue comes back if you reimport all projects. To fix it permanently remove the plugin Osmorc from intellij. 
You can do that by going to Intellij -> preferences -> Plugins 
Search for Osmorc and uncheck the checkbox and restart intellij

Answer (score 0):

As of IntelliJ IDEA version 2019.2, I was unable to find the Osmorc Plugin under installed plugins, instead, disabling OSGi plugin helped me.